# Randomize a Haskell list

Tags: list, haskell

I want to write a Haskell program that will "ramdomize" the elements in a list:

```
import System.Random (getStdGen, randomRIO)
import Data.List (permutations)

rndElem :: [a] -> IO a
rndElem xs = do
  index <- randomRIO (0, length xs - 2)
  return $ xs !! index

rndPermutation :: [a] -> IO [a]
rndPermutation xs = rndElem . permutations $ xs
```

However, running this does not seem to completely randomize the list. It only randomizes every other element, for some reason, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` --> `[5,2,1,4,3,6]`. Every run of this algorithm keeps the odd index (2, 4, 6) elements in the same spot..Is there any logic mistakes in the indexing of the above algorithm?

Comment: I ran this and got `[4,2,1,5,6,3]`.

Comment: Why the '2' in 'randomRIO (0, length xs - 2)'?

Comment: @ScottNewson isn't that the best way to ensure we randomize the list?

Comment: Like Chris, I do get results that look randomized - using Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3

Comment: @user327088 it's the best way to ensure that we never choose whichever the last permutation happens to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this code:

```
import System.Random (getStdGen, randomRIO)
import Data.List (permutations)

rndElem :: [a] -> IO Int
rndElem xs = do
  index <- randomRIO (0, length xs - 7)
  return index
```

and then change the 7 to a 6 to a 5 and so on.

Hopefully this explains my question about the '2', and maybe that will help you figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: Still not sure why you are getting the pattern you observe (odd index elements always in the same spot), as both Chris and I are not getting that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty nice algorithm for randomizing finite lists is the [Fisher-Yates shuffle, aka Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Here's the [Haskell version](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#Haskell) from Rosetta Code:

```
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

mkRands = mapM (randomRIO.(,)0 ). enumFromTo 1. pred

replaceAt :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceAt i c l = let (a,b) = splitAt i l in a++c:(drop 1 b)

swapElems :: (Int, Int) -> [a] -> [a]
swapElems (i,j) xs | i==j = xs
                   | otherwise = replaceAt j (xs!!i) $ replaceAt i (xs!!j) xs

knuthShuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
knuthShuffle xs =
  liftM (foldr swapElems xs. zip [1..]) (mkRands (length xs))
```